# Untangling a mess of partitions and bootloaders

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

After hours of trying to fix a dual boot system and trying to use almost every troubleshooting guide found by google, I finally have to give up and admit defeat.

I run a Win10/Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot system that worked fine until I tried to update Windows to a newer build.

I ran into an "Windows Update can't determine if you have enough space" error that supposedly was caused by having a dual boot system. Users reported that they had success by removing GRUB, updating Windows and (presumably) later installing GRUB again.

After first using EasyBCD (that caused my PC to *not* being able to load Windows anymore), then GRUB repair in Ubuntu, then Windows Media Creation Tool running `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` via cmd, I seem to have created a total mess. Nothing boots anymore and I have lost the overview of what is what.

Using Ubuntu Live and gparted, I can see the following:

```
/dev/sda                     223 GB
    /dev/sda1      NTFS      184 GB
    /dev/sda2      NTFS      450 MB   diag
    /dev/sda3      extended  39 GB    
        /dev/sda5  fat32     512 MB   boot,esp
        /dev/sda6  ext4      38.5 GB
/dev/sdb                     2.37 TB
    /dev/sdb1      unknown   16 MB    msftres
    /dev/sdb2      ntfs      2.73 TB  msftdata
```

/dev/sda is my SSD for OS and programs and /dev/sdb contains media, documents, dropbox etc
The name for sdb1 is "Microsoft reserved partition"

Can I clean this mess without losing windows? I would be willing to give up Ubuntu, as I don't have any important files there and I have another machine for Linux-related things.

Also, I'd like to end up without GRUB as it allegedly hinders Windows Update from updating the build.

I thought a few tutorials or guides would be all I needed, but it seems I am critically undereducated about booting and partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the main problem myself, i.e. booting to Windows and enabling the larger Windows10 update where the storage check failed due to GRUB (or Windows' ineptitude towards GRUB). Hopefully future me will find this answer useful.

The steps I took:

- Launch Ubuntu Live from USB
- Open the terminal and run ...

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

- In GRUB repair, choose *Restore MBR*
- In the tab MBR options tab (should not be grey anymore), choose in "Restore the MBR of" your drive with your OS (in my case my SSD) and in "Partition booted by the MBR" choose your windows partition.

Now when you restart your system should automatically boot into Windows. Good luck, future me!